# Specific Spanish per country on Android

Tags: android, localization, internationalization

I need to support different flavours of Spanish depending on the country.
That is, I need different strings for the Mexican Spanish.

[image]

Now, there are only 2 flavours available - Spanish Spanish and US Spanish:

[image]

So, how will my users select Mexican Spanish on their devices? How does android detect specific language?

Comment: Default localization is limited by the languages supported by the OS. If you want your users to select a custom language at runtime, your code is going to get ugly quick.

Comment: @jmateo So, what would you recommend? Android gives us possibility to use specific Spanish in resources, but how to select it on the phone?

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but you can give it a try: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-localization-at-runtime/